# Single keyword search in multiple notepad

Tags: vbscript

I have more than 200 notepads where i need to search two keyword. How could I search automatically instead manually checking each notepad?

Comment: 200 Notepads? As in NotePad windows? Or are you talking about something else

Comment: Do you just need to know if these two keywords appears in those files or you need to know the line number or the line that contains it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly:

"How can I more easily find two keywords of text within 200 or more text files on my computer?"

You could use a number of tools to help with that. Most of the more advanced text editors such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) and [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com) have features that easily enable you to find text in multiple files.

Alternatively, you could take a look at [Wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com) to find text in multiple files.